# C initialising both an array and a pointer in struct to the same value

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization

As the title, is it possible to initialize a pointer in a struct to point to the first element of an array that is also in the same struct?

```
struct foo
{
    int barr[12];
    int* barr_itt;
};

struct foo f = {{0}, /*.?.*/}
```

Comment: I'm curious about the application behind that question; syntactically, you now have a `struct{int*,int*};`.

Comment: yes, I have one pointer to itterate ofer the array, the other holds the location of the first element so it can be reset when it reaches the end.

Comment: wouldn't using `barr[index % 12]` achieve the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use the name of the variable

```
struct foo f = {{0}, f.barr} ;
```

Comment: Well that should be easy, Thanks!